# How does maven know to package web application?

Tags: java, maven, maven-package

I just used web-app archetype maven and develop in this style directory, calling the "mvn package" produces the right way of package, I found these configuration in eclipse by right click on application and deployment assembly, but where are these configurations located?

I think that they are maven related, not eclipse, so where they are?

Are they default for web-app archetype?

And how to add other con-fig paths  like src/main/java ->(deploy path) /WEB-INF/classes for packaging information?

Comment: Is there a `<packaging>war</packaging>` tag in `pom.xml`?

Comment: An archetype is basically a creation macro; it produces a POM and some files, but after that it's over, and you're just left with a Maven project. All of the information necessary for the build is in the POM.

Comment: @chrylis okey, but i don't have assembly paths like src/main/java ->(deploy path) /WEB-INF/classes in pom

Comment: Those are provided by the Super POM or the plugins that are included. Inspecting the effective POM may be helpful.